# Request moderator support for username change within 30 day limit

Tags: support, status-completed, display-names

I apologize in advance if this is an inappropriate request. However, I would like to know if a moderator is willing to help me with my stackexchange global username change. I already changed it once, but I made a mistake in it, thus I am forbidden to change it again for at least 30 days. I completely understand the time limit for user name change to prevent people from exploiting the system, however in my case I am not trying to hide something or take an advantage of something, I just made a silly mistake using a name that I normally dont use.

Best regards

Comment: Can you specify what you'd actually like the new name to be?

Comment: I would like it to be: metabuddy

Comment: Thank you Grace :) I appreciate your help!

Comment: metabuddy == a friend of friends?

Comment: @MartijnPieters something like that :) hard to explain. I really liked the idea about [metagaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metagaming) so I borrowed the term